# The Algebra of Limits - Product rule

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation

Theorem: let $\ell,m \in \mathbb{R}$ and suppose that $ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(a_n)=\ell$ and $ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(b_n)=m$.

Prove that $$(a_n \cdot b_n) \to \ell \cdot m.$$

I do not understand how it was chosen for $|b_n -m| \lt \frac{\epsilon}{2(1+|\ell|)}$, in order for the final part of the proof to be:

$|a_nb_n-\ell m| \lt \frac{\epsilon}{2M} \cdot M + \frac{\epsilon}{2(1+|\ell|)}\cdot |\ell| \leq \epsilon.$

Here $M \in \mathbb{R}$ and denotes the bound for $b_n$ ($|b_n| \leq M \,\, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}).$

Comment: Look at the definition of convergence, for "any given" $\epsilon > 0$, there exists, $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|b_n-m| < \epsilon$ $\forall n>N$. Focus on the part, any given $\epsilon > 0$. SInce $\frac{\epsilon}{2(1+|l|)}$ is positive, we can set this to be our new $\epsilon$ in the definition of convergence and proceed with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So somewhere in the proof, you end up with:
$$|a_nb_n-\ell m| \lt \frac{\epsilon}{2M} \cdot M + \color{blue}{\frac{\epsilon}{2(1+|\ell|)}}\cdot |\ell| \leq \epsilon.$$
where the blue expression is an upper bound for $|b_n-m|$.

Since $b_n \to m$, this factor can be made arbitrarily small and $\frac{\epsilon}{2|\ell|}$ would do the trick but this would require an exception in the case where $\ell=0$. You can avoid this by choosing the upper bound in blue, adding the "$+1$" to avoid the denominator ever becoming $0$.

Answer (score 0):

First, $\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists n_0\mid \forall n>n_0.\ |a_n-\ell|<\varepsilon_1$

You have $$|a_nb_n-\ell m|=|a_nb_n-b_n\ell+b_n\ell-\ell m|=|b_n(a_n-\ell)+\ell(b_n-m)|$$ Now, by the triangle inequality $$|a_nb_n-\ell m|\le |b_n||a_n-\ell|+|\ell||b_n-m|$$ We know that $|a_n-\ell|<\varepsilon_1$ and $|b_n-m|<\varepsilon_2$ and $b_n$ is bounded, i.e we have $$|a_nb_n-\ell m|< M\varepsilon_1+|\ell|\varepsilon_2$$ Choosing $\varepsilon_1<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2M}$ and $\varepsilon_2<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2|\ell|}$ will give $|a_nb_n-\ell m|<\varepsilon$. We want to avoid dividing by $0$, hence we choose $\varepsilon_2=\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2(|\ell|+1)}$.